# setnames() in a list object in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation, tidy

I have a list object below and I need to assign each list object with a specific name such as if the object is in the `1st` place in `my.list`, `DF.1`, if it is in the `10th` place, DF.10. Many thanks in advance.

```
df1 <- data_frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1],1:4), valueA = seq(0.1,0.4,0.1), Category= "Apples", valueDEF = seq(0.1,0.4,0.1), valueDEF2 = seq(0.1,0.4,0.1) )
    df2 <- data_frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1],5:8), valueB = seq(0.1,0.4,0.1),  Category= "Apples2")
    df3 <- data_frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1],9:12), valueC = seq(0.1,0.4,0.1),  Category= "Apples3")
    
    my.list  <- list(df1, df2, df3);my.list 
    
    for(i in 1:length(my.list)){
      my.list[[i]] <-  paste("DF", i, sep = ".")
      #names(my.list) <- setNames(my.list , c('list1', 'list2', 'list3')) ### in forloop 
    }
```

EXPECTED ANSWER

```
 names(my.list) 
DF.1, DF.2, DF.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can combine `paste` (create the names) with `setNames` (assign the names to the list):

```
names(my.list) <- paste0("DF.", 1:length(my.list))

names(my.list)
[1] "DF.1" "DF.2" "DF.3"
```